# XPath: Select node with condition on child of sibling

Tags: xml, xpath

In an android app I am trying to select all `ActueleVertrekTijd` nodes where the child `VervoerType` of the first `ReisDeel` node equals `Intercity`.

I have the following xml structure:

```
<ReisMogelijkheden>
    <ReisMogelijkheid>
        <ActueleVertrekTijd>time1</ActueleVertrekTijd>
        <ReisDeel>
            <VervoerType>Intercity</VervoerType>
        </ReisDeel
        <ReisDeel>
            <VervoerType>Intercity</VervoerType>
        </ReisDeel>
    </ReisMogelijkheid>
    <ReisMogelijkheid>
        <ActueleVertrekTijd>time2</ActueleVertrekTijd>
        <ReisDeel>
            <VervoerType>Sprinter</VervoerType>
        </ReisDeel
        <ReisDeel>
            <VervoerType>Intercity</VervoerType>
        </ReisDeel>
    </ReisMogelijkheid>
</ReisMogelijkheden>
```

In this case I would want it to return just time1.

After some hours of googling I tried various things, under which the best were:

```
/ReisMogelijkheden/ReisMogelijkheid/Reisdeel[1][child::VervoerType/self::text()='Intercity']/ActueleVertrekTijd
/ReisMogelijkheden/ReisMogelijkheid[Reisdeel[VervoerType[text()='Intercity']]]]/ActueleVertrekTijd

/ReisMogelijkheden/ReisMogelijkheid[Reisdeel[child::VervoerType/self::text()='Intercity']]/ActueleVertrekTijd
/ReisMogelijkheden/ReisMogelijkheid[child::Reisdeel[child::VervoerType/self::text()='Intercity']]/ActueleVertrekTijd

/ReisMogelijkheden/ReisMogelijkheid/Reisdeel[VervoerType[text()='Intercity']]/../ActueleVertrekTijd
```

But none of them returned something. XPath is hard to debug because it gives no error messages, so I'm stuck now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//ReisMogelijkheid[ReisDeel[1]/VervoerType = "Intercity"]/ActueleVertrekTijd
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! I had to change the double quotes to single quotes because it's a java String, but it works perfectly.